# Oracle PL/SQL - check if input parameter is a directory

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on a package that passes file names from a directory as the `in_file_name` parameter, but the calling program is also passing the sub-directory names and it should not. Right now I am aborting the package if the `in_file_name` is a sub-directory by doing the following:

```
    IF in_file_name IN ('sub_dir_1','sub_dir_2','sub_dir_3')
    THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
```

However, I can forsee issues in the future if any new directories are created. Is there way to check if the `in_file_name` is a directory instead of hard-coding the names?

One possibility I can think of is run `UTIL_OS.run_cmd('echo */')` to get a list of directories. But i'm not sure how to get the output and use it in that `IF` statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the files/directories you're checking under an OS directory that exists as an Oracle DIRECTORY object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working with a directory object and the passed file name is a file (or directory) under that, you could use the [`utl_file.fgetattr()` procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70915) to test it; if the passed name is a file the `fexists` flag will be true, and if it doesn't exist or is a directory rather than a plain file then it will be false. (That doesn't seem to be documented; but it's how it works on Linux, at least).

So you'd need to declare some extra variables, but could then do:

```
utl_file.fgetattr(
  location => your_directory,
  filename => in_file_name,
  fexists => l_fexists,
  file_length => l_file_length,
  block_size => l_block_size);

if not l_fexists then
  -- handle file not existing OR being a directory
end if;
```

Comment: When I tried to compile it, `IF !l_fexists` causes a `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "!"`